# Making  a new environment combining equation and split

Tags: equations, environments, errors

I'm trying to define a new environment that consists of a `split` environment inside an `equation` environment. But I'm getting an error. Here's what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{example}{\begin{equation}\begin{split}}{\end{split}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}oi\end{example}
\end{document}
```

And the error message I'm getting is:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: \begin{split} on input line 8 ended by \end{example}.
```

I then tried a few other cases. If I remove the `split`s and define `example` to be just `equation`, it runs fine. If I remove the `equation`s and define `example` to be just `split`, I get the exact same error message.

In other words: I only get this error when `split` is involved. Is there a way to make this work?

EDIT: The reason I'm doing this, is because I want a convenient way to create `split`-equations. I know it's similar to `align`. I prefer `split`-equations because the entire line of equations gets a single number for referencing (it's even placed in the middle line). `align`, however, will force me to `\notag` each line, otherwise I get a number for each line in the equation (which tends to get messy when equations are long and numerous). It's not the end of the world, but the `split`-`equation` combination is just quicker and easier (if I can manage to define a command for it).

Alternatively, the `multline` environment is not appropriate either, because it doesn't let you manually align each line (like aligning the equal signs). Instead it only lets you push everything left or right.

EDIT2: I just tried this:

```
\newenvironment{example}{ \begin{equation}\split}{\endsplit \end{equation}}
```

and got this error

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: \begin{equation} on input line 8 ended by \end{example}.
```

Which is weird, because removing `\split` and `\endsplit` entirely doesn't return any errors (so it's not `equation`'s fault).

Comment: What do you get if you replace the `\begin{split}` by `\split` and the `\end{split}` by `\endsplit` in your environment definition?

Comment: Could you change the question, so that it makes more sense? You say you're using split inside equation, but your example code does not show this. Also you have the error message located on line 14 and there is no line 14. Andrew's suggestion seems to work for me, however.

Comment: @Andrew Just out of curiosity, will it still work in LaTeX3?  Is that even a concern?

Comment: @Jan I have absolutely no idea!  I don't even know how to test something under LaTeX3.

Comment: @frabjous: Ok, I'm editing the question.

Comment: @Andrew: Just tried, doesn't work either, but the error message is different.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I wouldn't have expected this, but there's an easy answer; [thanks to Stefan Kottwitz!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5639/defining-a-new-environment-whose-contents-go-in-a-tikz-node/5642#5642) (And thanks to Will Robertson for writing the package `environ` that I had never heard of before. He should have given this answer; with his package it works like a charm.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,environ}
\NewEnviron{example}{%
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
  \BODY
\end{split}\end{equation}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
a &= b + c \\
  &= d + e
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Some explanations can be found in Stefan's post behind the above link.

Comment: i did this. problem: if you now label your example environment, it increases the equation counter by 2. why is this? how can it be fixed other than hardcoded and hacky \addtocounter{equation}{-1} before BODY?

Comment: oh no, just made a MWE and it doesnt happen there. any idea what might cause this behavior?

Comment: i found the culprit: \usepackage[thref,amsmath]{ntheorem}, removing any one of the options fixes the problem, having them both, causes it. on to reading why they were put there in the first place ...

Answer (score 24):

The reason that `\begin{split} ... \end{split}` doesn't work when the `\begin ... \end` are invoked within the begin and end parts of another environment is related to the reason given in the "technical notes on the amsmath package" (texdoc technote) -- the parsing requires an exact match of the environment specified by `\begin{...}`.

this isn't really obvious from the current documentation in technote, but it would be a good idea to add it, and I'll try to arrange for that to happen.

Answer (score 6):

The `split` environment has to be used within a math displaying environment. I guess that what you are trying to do is to create a shortcut so that you don't have to write

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
...
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

every time.

Perhaps an alternative to `split` would be the `aligned` environment which also allows you align a sequence of formulas on the equal sign and, placing it inside an `equation` environment, you also get a single equation number for the whole expression. Also luckily, `aligned` doesn't have the parsing problems of `split` and plays well with new environment definitions.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{equations}{\equation\aligned}{\endaligned\endequation}

\begin{equations}
a &= b + c \\
  &= d + e
\end{equations}
```

Of course, you can always read the documentation from amsmath by typing

```
texdoc amsldoc
```

on a command line to find inspiration and browse for alternatives.

Comment: Yes, you're correct about my intentions, and I know about align. I would rather use equation-split than align, because align numbers (for reference) every single line of equations, while split only numbers the very middle line (and thus looks better). I know I could just use `\notag` tons of time (it's what I've been doing this far) but it would be 10 times better if I could have a shortcut for a split-equation.

Comment: As someone who uses the `align` environment by default for all of his mathematics, I find the idea that `align` would be an alternative to `split` a bit odd anyway — for me, `split` is an environment to control the numbering  of my equations in `align`, as it is for Bruce with `equation`.

Comment: And what about `multline`? would that be suitable?

Comment: From what I understand, `multline` does not let you align the equal signs. I need that, because I'm using strings of several equations that constitute steps towards a final equation. Instead, `multline` seems more suitable when you have a single equation that's too big for a single line.

Comment: Maybe then the `aligned` environment is what you're looking for? I've edited my answer with a new proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to Juan's answer: declaring a new environment using `equation` and `aligned` does work, but it introduces some added wrinkles with spacing.  It seems to include a single space (smaller than an indent) in the text which follows the equation.  I'll quote [the relevant wikibooks page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX#Extra_space):

> When creating a new environment you
>   may easily get bitten by extra spaces
>   creeping in, which can potentially
>   have fatal effects. For example when
>   you want to create a title environment
>   which suppresses its own indentation
>   as well as the one on the following
>   paragraph. The `\ignorespaces`  command
>   in the begin block of the environment
>   will make it ignore any space after
>   executing the begin block. The end
>   block is a bit more tricky as special
>   processing occurs at the end of an
>   environment. With the
>   `\ignorespacesafterend` LaTeX will issue
>   an `\ignorespaces` after the special
>   ‘end’ processing has occurred

Including `ignorespaces` in the new environment definition seems to be weirdly behaved.  Dealing with this subtle spacing issue seems like too much trouble for just a shortcut.  I recommend writing out the full

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
     ...
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

using auto-completion, like with TexWorks or TeXShop.  (`\begin{align}\begin{split}` seems to be just as good in this context where we aren't defining new environments.)  This has the added benefit of being easier to read for anyone else (*e.g.*, a journal) looking at your LaTeX.