# Defining a new environment whose contents go in a TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, environments

I would like to define an environment which typesets the contents in a box, and I'd like to use TikZ (I'm aware of alternatives like fancybox). So I would like something like

```
\newenvironment{abox}%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}\node(box){\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}}%
  {\end{minipage}};}
```

However, this doesn't work, because the `{...}` that wraps the TikZ node can't be split across the beginning and end of the environment. Is there anyway around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In such cases the [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) page comes handy. Its command `\NewEnviron` collects the body which can be accessed as `\BODY` macro within your definition. Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{abox}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node(box){%
        \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
          \BODY
        \end{minipage}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{abox}
  Text
\end{abox}
\end{document}
```

This compiles without problems and draws the test box.

Comment: Didn't know about that one. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the `environ` package; extremely useful also for [other things](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/making-a-new-environment-combining-equation-and-split/5652#5652) (shameless plug). @Stefan, only one thing: `\NewEnviron` takes only 2 mandatory arguments (and one optional argument behind those); it won't see the pair of braces `{}`.

Comment: Remark: Will break verbatim commands inside nodes however.

Answer (score 10):

First of all: I never knew about `environ` and am impressed.  My answer is not nearly so good, but I learned it from the LaTeX sources so it should count for something.

Try writing

```
\newenvironment{<stuff>{\iffalse}\fi}
               {\iffalse{\fi}<stuff>}
```

`<stuff>`, of course, is what you wrote.  The point is that there are no unbalanced braces in this construction, because when parsing macro arguments, TeX does not actually expand anything, in particular, `\iffalse`.  Thus, the "commented out" braces are present for the purposes of reading in the contents of the environment commands, and then absent for the purposes of executing them.

EDIT: In this and many other cases, the much simpler expedient of `\bgroup...\egroup` works too:

```
\newenvironment{<stuff>\bgroup}
               {\egroup<stuff>}
```

Since `\bgroup` is `\let` to equal `{` and `\egroup` is `\let` to `}`, this (in theory) is synonymous with using braces, except that (since these "implicit characters" don't count as far as nesting inside arguments being parsed is concerned) it doesn't break definitions.

Occasionally you come across a situation where literal braces are required; `\def` itself is an example.  You *must* write

```
\def\cs{<def'n>}
```

and not

```
\def\cs\bgroup<def'n>\egroup
```

but in many higher-level constructions (including, my quick test shows, TikZ) this is not a problem.

Comment: +1, nice explanations. I'm not so sure about the trick with `\iffalse`: It looks useful, but is there any instance where you can use this trick, and `\bgroup` + `\egroup` doesn't work? (For `\def` it doesn't seem to help!)

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Unfortunately `\def` is totally inflexible!  So that was a bad example.  But I have found exactly one situation where this trick is necessary: with `\halign`.  See, `\halign` allows you to protect `&`s and `\cr`s appearing inside its entries (as in, within a nested `\halign`) by surrounding them in `{...}`.  These are required to be literal braces.  So if you have an environment where an alignment entry is broken from `\begin` to `\end`, you need to use the `\iffalse` trick if you want to protect its contents.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: By the way, you can make it work in `\def` if you unbalance the `\iffalse` trick: just write `\def\cs{...\iffalse{\fi}`.  `\def` doesn't care if the inside has apparently unbalanced opening braces, but if the `\iffalse{\fi}` appears inside *another* macro argument, it will have properly balanced *closing* braces, which `\def` does care about. Of course, writing `\def\cs{\iffalse}\fi...\iffalse{\fi}` makes `\cs = \iffalse` and then gives an error as soon as `\def` finishes because you have a lonely `\fi` (unless you are in another conditional, when you get a subtler error...).

Comment: Why do you say that your answer is not as good? With the `\bgroup`/`\egroup` trick, the text inside the environment can have verbatim in it, which the `environ` package does not allow.

Comment: @Philippe Goutet: I added `\bgroup`/`\egroup` after I made that comment.  In my opinion, the `\iffalse` trick is just that: a trick, and not something to be recommended.  As it is, I guess what I wrote is not so bad anymore.