# Defining a command for amsmath's align environment

Tags: environments, amsmath, align

I'd like to define a shorthand command for `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}`. When I write

```
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{align*}}
```

it works fine. But when I write

```
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{align*}}
```

LaTeX complains. It looks like it's interpreting it as part of the environment and is not happy with that. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This seems the sort of thing you should have a shortcut for in your editor, rather than in LaTeX itself.

Answer (score 18):

An alternative solution -- this is the code in the custom document class I use for everything:

```
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}
```

Usage:

```
\eq{
  x^2 + 9 &= 0
}
```

(Obviously, change the command name to suit your preference.)

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I defined the \eq command, and it's working well.

Comment: This is a great idea, thank you. What does the [1] signify?

Comment: It's the number of arguments your new `\eq` command will require. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros for more information.

Answer (score 6):

A little testing shows that this appears to be fairly specific to the "align" environment from amsmath.  For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\bc}{\begin{center}}
\newcommand{\ec}{\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\bc
hello world
\ec

\end{document}
```

works fine.  I'm not sure why `align*` doesn't work (it doesn't work without the star either); I suspect that the myriad expansions and aliases surrounding the align environment do something a little more complicated than a "traditional" LaTeX environment.  However, I have found something that might just achieve the same objective for you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ba}{\[\begin{aligned}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{aligned}\]}

\begin{document}

\ba
x^2 &= y^2 \\
z^2 &= t^2
\ea

\end{document}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it's a bug.

```
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{align}} 
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{align}}
\ba
x=1
\ea
```

LaTeX complains about `align` not being closed.

Comment: This is not a bug, but indeed unexpected behaviour of `align`. It's explained [over at tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/making-a-new-environment-combining-equation-and-split/3205#3205)