# Defining an abbreviation for `align`

Tags: macros, article

To save myself some keystrokes, I tried to define an abbreviation for `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`

```
\documentclass[reqno, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amsthm}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{align*}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{align*}}

\title{Article Template}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{3}
\ba
e=mc^2
\ea
\end{document}
```

For some reason, the abbreviation for `\begin{align}` seems to work, but the abbreviation for `\end{align}` does not. I thought perhaps that `\ea` was already in use, but tweaking the name didn't change anything. Any ideas?

Comment: You should definitely do that using your editor instead of TeX. TeX code is a markup and `ba`, `ea` don't carry any structural information. Many editors have a *snippet* or *expansion* function, so you can write `ba<hotkey>` to expand to `\begin{align}`.

Comment: @Marco Thanks for the input. I use writelatex.com, which isn't a very sophisticated editor, so that might not be an option.

Comment: This is a documented feature of ams alignments, they need to grab the entire body of the environment as a macro so that it can be set twice (for measuring) so the code needs to find `\end{align}` to know when to stop the argument. It is possible (but discouraged) to work around that: see the amsmath documentation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, I guess I'll just have to make the extra keystrokes. :)

Comment: there's a good answer to this question at [some \newcommand instructions not working](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112558/579)

Comment: See also [Defining a shorthand for amsmath's align environment (as commands)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13042/), for example. Lots of possible 'main questions', just a question of which to pick for  a dupe, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks Joseph and Barbara; there are some great suggestions at those links!