# Starred equivalent in newenvironment

Tags: environments, starred-version

Let's say I want to use the `align`-environment in a `newenvironment` like this:

```
\newenvironment{mequation}{\align}{\endalign}
```

This works fine. However, what if I want to use the starred version of `align*`?

```
\newenvironment{mequation}{\align*}{\endalign*}
```

Doesn't seem to work.. Any ideas?

Comment: I expect there is a simple xparse solution to this: defining a starred and non-starred version at the same time...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`*` cannot be used for the name of a control sequence. You must use the `\csname`...`\endcsname` pair here :

```
\newenvironment{mequation}{\csname align*\endcsname}{\csname endalign*\endcsname}
```

Comment: Good answer. One should note that `\newenvironment{mequation}{\begin{align*}}{\end{align*}}` does not work. It's the same problem as with `split`, [explained here by barbara beeton](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/making-a-new-environment-combining-equation-and-split/3205#3205).