# Errors when trying to define a custom align environment

Tags: environments, align

I'm currently trying to create a custom environment with its own counter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\newcounter{grammarcounter}

\newenvironment{grammar}{
   \refstepcounter{grammarcounter}
   \begin{equation*}
   \tag{$\Gamma_{\thegrammarcounter}$}
   }{\end{equation*}}
\numberwithin{grammarcounter}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
\label{gr:label}
E ::= E + E \\
E ::= a
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

This works nicely for simple equations, but the line split \\ does not work inside the equation* environment. Ideally I would like to replace the equation* environment with the align* environment. However, when simply replacing equation* in the example with align*, I get LaTeX errors indicating \begin{align} on input line .. ended by \end{grammar}.

How can I create a custom equation environment with its own counter that respects line breaks?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You probably want to use the `aligned` (or `gathered`) environment nested in `grammar`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know of the existence of the aligned environment. I've added \begin{aligned} after \tag{} and \end{aligned} before \end{equation*} and now it works perfectly! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why but you can't use `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` in the definition of a new environment; you have to use the "lower-level" macros `\align` and `\endalign` instead. **Edit**: as pointed by [alexwlchan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9668/alexwlchan) in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162885/errors-when-trying-to-define-a-custom-align-environment/162895?noredirect=1#comment373539_162895), you can find more details about that in section 6 of [Technical notes on the `amsmath` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/technote.pdf).

Here I've used the equivalent of an `align*` environment (see [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24944/21891) to [Define a custom align, and align* environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24939/define-a-custom-align-and-align-environment)).

Note that you will get an error if you try to reset your `grammarcounter` at each chapter in the `article` class, because the latter doesn't have chapters; `\section` is the most high-level sectioning command in the `article` class. Did you mean

```
\numberwithin{grammarcounter}{section}
```

instead?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{grammarcounter}[section]

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{grammar}
{%
  \refstepcounter{grammarcounter}
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne
  \tag{$\Gamma_{\thegrammarcounter}$}
}{%
  \endalign
}
\makeatother
 
\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\begin{grammar}
\label{gr:label}
E &::= E + E \\
E &::= a     \\
E &::= b     
\end{grammar}

\begin{grammar}
\label{gr:label2}
E &::= E + E \\
E &::= a     \\
E &::= b     
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Section 6 of `technote.pdf` has a little more detail on why you can't use abbreviations for the `{align}` environment: <http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/technote.pdf>

Comment: @alexwlchan The link is dead...

Comment: @Jubobs: sorry, I made a Markdown error. Here's a working link: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/technote.pdf

Comment: @alexwlchan Thanks for the link; it's helpful! I'll add the reference to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can nest `aligned` or `split` in the `grammar` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[fleqn,tbtags]{amsmath}

\newcounter{grammarcounter}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thegrammarcounter}{\thechapter.\arabic{grammarcounter}}

\newenvironment{grammar}
  {\refstepcounter{grammarcounter}
   \begin{equation*}
   \tag{$\Gamma_{\thegrammarcounter}$}}
  {\end{equation*}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Start}

\begin{grammar}
\label{gr:label}
\begin{aligned}
E &::= E + E \\
E &::= a
\end{aligned}
\end{grammar}

\begin{grammar}
\label{gr:label-two}
\begin{split}
E &::= E + E \\
E &::= a
\end{split}
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

Using `split` without the `tbtags` option is equivalent to `aligned` (the number will be vertically centered). So I presented two examples to show the difference, adding the option.

[image]

I wouldn't make `grammar` into an automatically multiline environment, as spacing considerations are involved. You can define a `mlgrammar` environment, if you want:

```
\newenvironment{mlgrammar}
  {\begin{grammar}\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\end{grammar}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally, I was also making a custom align environment for grammars. I'm not using left-aligned equations (so no `fleqn` option for `amsmath`), but I did want the grammars to be left-aligned. Here's an environment-based solution that could help someone in a similar situation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\nr\relax%          https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512854/203081
\usepackage{nccmath}  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467619/203081

\newlength{\grammarindent}
\setlength{\grammarindent}{3em}
\newcounter{grammarcounter}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thegrammarcounter}{\thechapter.\arabic{grammarcounter}}

\newenvironment{grammar}
{%
    \refstepcounter{grammarcounter}%
    \begin{fleqn}[\grammarindent]\begin{equation*}\left\{\:\tag{$G_{\thegrammarcounter}$}\begin{aligned}%
}%
{%
    \end{aligned}\right.\end{equation*}\par\end{fleqn}% You need the \par to prevent \end{fleqn} from acting like a space.
}


\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}\label{gr:label}
    E &::= E + E \\
    E &::= a
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

`nccmath` provides the `fleqn` environment. I'm not sure why the above answers don't include the `aligned` inside the new `grammar` environment, but I have done so here and it works fine.