# Command \nr already defined (datetime2 and nccmath incompatibility)

Tags: errors, incompatibility, datetime2, nccmath

It seems that the `datetime2` and the `nccmath` packages are incompatible when I load the `[useregional]` option in the first (I get `command \nr already defined`).

I used a solution for reducing spacing around my equations that needed the latter, and I suppose I could find another one just as easily (even though maybe not as convenient), but maybe someone here could find a way to fix this.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Example}
\author{Isabella B.}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \lipsum[1]

    \useshortskip

    \[ 2\times2=4 \]

    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `nccmath` `\useshortskip` command still works, but maybe some other functionality is being compromised.

With `\useshortskip`:

[image]

Without `\useshortskip`:

[image]

Comment: Change the order of  packages loading: first `nccmath` than `datetime2`

Comment: The update to `datetime2`, v1.5.4 dated 2019/10/21 solves the issue. See https://www.dickimaw-books.com/bugtracker.php?action=view&key=137

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they have a small incompatibility. The `nccmath` defines `\nr` to be equivalent to `\\[0.5ex]`. If you will not use this shortcut, then the solution proposed by @Zarko will work: `nccmath` will define `\nr` and `datetime2` will overwrite it without problems.

But if you would like to have the `\nr` shortcut then that won't work. `datetime2` uses `\nr` as a temporary macro to hold a number. You can redefine that to use another name, so the clash doesn't happen. Add this to your preamble after loading `datetime2` and before `nccmath`:

```
\makeatletter
\define@choicekey{datetime2.sty}{useregional}[\DTM@val\DTM@nr]%
 {false,text,numeric,num}[text]%
 {%
   \ifcase\DTM@nr\relax
     \renewcommand*{\DTMifcaseregional}[3]{##1}%
   \or
     \renewcommand*{\DTMifcaseregional}[3]{##2}%
   \or
     \renewcommand*{\DTMifcaseregional}[3]{##3}%
   \or
     \renewcommand*{\DTMifcaseregional}[3]{##3}%
   \fi
 }
\let\nr\relax
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\makeatletter
\define@choicekey{datetime2.sty}{useregional}[\DTM@val\DTM@nr]%
 {false,text,numeric,num}[text]%
 {%
   \ifcase\DTM@nr\relax
     \renewcommand*{\DTMifcaseregional}[3]{##1}%
   \or
     \renewcommand*{\DTMifcaseregional}[3]{##2}%
   \or
     \renewcommand*{\DTMifcaseregional}[3]{##3}%
   \or
     \renewcommand*{\DTMifcaseregional}[3]{##3}%
   \fi
 }
\let\nr\relax
\makeatother
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Example}
\author{Isabella B.}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \lipsum[1]

    \useshortskip

    \[ 2\times2=4 \]

    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The usage of `\nr` stems from examples in the manual of `xkeyval` (see page 6); it's wrong: a scratch macro used by a package should always have `@` in its name. On the other hand, I have no clue as to why `nccmath` chose the name `\nr` for ``\\[0.5ex]``.

Comment: I filed a bug report. By the way, also `\val` should be changed in, say, `\DTM@val`

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your comments. Now I understand why these macro names were used. I am going fix `\val` in my answer.

Comment: It turns out that the optional argument to `\define@choicekey` should consist of two tokens that are used as scratch macros. Neither `\val` nor `\nr` appear in the package code; when checking with `\tracingmacros=1`, I found that the code does `\def\val{...}`, where `\val` is absorbed as the first argument to a macro, the second argument, in the example case is `\nr` that receives various integer values according to the number of items in the following argument.

Comment: @egreg Oh, I think I get it. For example, `\val` would be `text`, and then `\nr` would be `1` (which is then used in the `\ifcase`). So the name of these two macros don't really matter as long as they are the same as in the code of the option... After your comment I tried to understand the code in `xkeyval` but I got lost after the 7th or 8th variation of `\XKV@d@f@ne@ch@ic@k@y` XD

Answer (score 4):

You can load packages in this order,  neutralising the `\nr` command from `nccmath`:

```
\usepackage{nccmath}%
\let\nr\relax%
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
```

You can replace the `nccmath \nr` either with what it's for: `\\[0.5ex]`, or use the `linespread` environment from `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case).

Comment: That's what @Zarko said in the comment and I in my answer. Perhaps `\let\NCnr\nr\let\nr\relax` to preserve the `\nr` command somewhere...

Comment: Excellent suggestion!