# Wrapping environment in another environment with hooks

Tags: environments, hooks

This problem is distilled from an environment that needs to use its body either wrapped in a minipage or not. Furthermore, this environment is to be automatically wrapped around all uses of another environment (e.g. `flushleft` in the following).

Explicitly wrapping `myEnv` around another environment works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{O{}+b}
  {B {#2}}
  {{#2} E}

\begin{document}

\begin{myEnv}
\begin{flushleft}
  flushleft
\end{flushleft}
\end{myEnv}

\end{document}
```

However, if I try to use environment hooks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{O{}+b}
  {B {#2}}
  {{#2} E}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{flushleft}{\begin{myEnv}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{flushleft}{\end{myEnv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
  body
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

then I get this error:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\environment myEnv code #1#2->B {#2}
                                    
l.17 \end
         {flushleft}
```

To reiterate, I'd like to have all uses of the `flushleft` environment to be modified as if they were explicitly wrapped in `myEnv`.
What's wrong with the above? Maybe the `myEnv` hooks are invoked for more times than I expect them to?

Comment: Am I missing something or both of your code examples are exactly the same?

Comment: Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `+b` argument is not correctly recognized by `myEnv` when `flushleft` is redefined with the hooks. I think what happens is that `flushleft` can't pass the body as an argument to `myEnv`, because it simply does not take it as an argument in the first place. I see two solutions here.

1. Remove the body from `myEnv`'s definition if you don't really need it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{O{}}
  {B}
  {E}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{flushleft}{\begin{myEnv}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{flushleft}{\end{myEnv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
  body
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

2. Redefine `flushleft` so that it understands the body as an argument. In that case you don't need the hooks, because you already redefine `flushleft` so you can just add `myEnv` in the new definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{O{} +b}
  {B {#2}}
  {{#2} E}
\let\oldflushleft\flushleft
\let\endoldflushleft\endflushleft
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{flushleft}{+b}
    {\begin{myEnv}\oldflushleft #1}
    {\endoldflushleft\end{myEnv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
  body
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand how I'm "trying to use the +b argument, which is the body of the environment, inside of the flushleft environment". I thought that the point of the BeforeBegin and AfterEnd hooks was that they are run outside the flushleft?

Comment: @melisgl Yes you're right, maybe it was not the best choice of words. What I meant was that with the hooks, the body is not correctly recognized by `myEnv`. I don't know much about how the hooks and the `+b` argument work under the hood, but a similar example without the `+b` argument works with the hooks so I figured this was causing the problem. Anyway, I changed the wording.

Comment: Thank you. Something is not quite right though because if I do replace `flushleft` with `equation` I get this error: `Extra }, or forgotten $. \environment myEnv code #1#2->B {#2} l.17 \end{equation}`.

Comment: It may be this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162885/errors-when-trying-to-define-a-custom-align-environment.