# Pass body of arbitrary environment to hooked command

Tags: luatex, environments, expl3, hooks

I'd like to inject a command into an arbitrary environment that uses the environment body as an argument.

#### Desired behavior

```
\begin{AnyEnvironment}{MandatoryEnvArg}[OptionalEnvArg]
  ...
\end{AnyEnvironment}
```

Should expand to

```
\begin{AnyEnvironment}{MandatoryEnvArg}[OptionalEnvArg]
  \MyMacro{...}
\end{AnyEnvironment}
```

Where `...` are arbitrary contents (possibly including `\par`s and other environments and commands).

#### Use Case

My use case for this perhaps odd question is the following: I want to be able to "preprocess" the environment body with `\MyMacro`. In particular, `\MyMacro` would be a command which itself invokes a Lua command with `\directlua` that would receive the environment body as a string and perform some string manipulation on it before putting it back into TeX's input stream. As a basic example:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{m}
  {
    \directlua
      {
        local str = "\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}"
        tex.sprint(str .. ' ~ ' .. str)
      }
  }
```

Even more specifically, this all started because I was curious whether I could implement support for "shorthand" syntaxes (such as the one used in [`typst`](https://typst.app), a LaTeX-like typesetting program) in math mode. Basic experiments of mine yielded surprisingly nice results, so I became curious how far I could bring this kind of functionality in LaTeX, hence the generality of my question.

#### Requirements

- `AnyEnvironment` may be any feasible LaTeX environment. In particular, it may:

  - Be user-defined.
  - Be defined by external packages.
  - Be inside of math mode (e.g., `aligned`), or activate math mode itself (e.g., `align`).
  - Have any kinds of arguments.
  - May have asterisks (`*`) or dashes (`-`) in its name.
  - *Contain verbatin content and/or catcode changes* — It seems that supporting this would be very difficult (as per comments to this question).

#### Approaches

##### Redefining environment

```latex
\let\oldAnyEnvironment\AnyEnvironment
\let\endoldAnyEnvironment\endAnyEnvironment
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{AnyEnvironment}{+b}
  {\oldAnyEnvironment\MyMacro{#1}}{\endoldAnyEnvironment}
```

**Issues**:

- Doesn't work if `AnyEnvironment` has arguments
- Doesn't work if `AnyEnvironment` has `*` (asterisk) or `-` (dash) in its name (though this might be easily fixable, I've seen starred environments be referred to by `\<env>star` and `\end<env>star`, and maybe there's something similar for dashes).

##### With hooks

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \MyMacro } { m } { Argument:~#1. }
\AtBeginEnvironment { AnyEnvironment } { \MyMacro \bgroup }
\AtEndEnvironment   { AnyEnvironment } { \egroup }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

**Issues**:

- Doesn't work; `\bgroup` and `\egroup` aren't the right thing to use for this purpose (also see [Arguments possibly delimited by \bgroup and \egroup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196776/170958)). However, this approach feels more promising to me. I tried reading into the `l3basics` and `l3quark` modules, since I was hopeful that I could find an answer there; for example, `\use_none_delimit_by_q_stop:w ... \q_stop` made me think that maybe something similar could be used to collect the environment body. However, I didn't manage to find a solution yet.

---

*Related questions*:

- [Wrapping environment in another environment with hooks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/672539/170958)

*Related packages*:

- [`environ`](https://ctan.org/pkg/environ) – A new interface for environments in LaTeX

  - Defines `\BODY` and `\Collect@Body` commands
- [`xparse`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) – A generic document command parser

  - Defines `b` and `+b` argument types
- [`amsmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) – AMS mathematical facilities for LaTeX

  - Defines `\collect@body` command

---

Basic non-working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\NewDocumentEnvironment { AnyEnvironment } {} {} {}
\NewDocumentCommand { \MyMacro } { m } { Contents: ~ #1. }
\AtBeginEnvironment { AnyEnvironment } { \MyMacro \bgroup }
\AtEndEnvironment { AnyEnvironment } { \egroup }

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{AnyEnvironment}
Example.
\end{AnyEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151322/discussion-on-question-by-steve-pass-body-of-arbitrary-environment-to-hooked-com); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.