# Left aligned multi line equations and \newenvironment

Tags: tables, environments, align

I'm building a table of integrals, for my own use. I need simple things: equations must be left aligned, sometimes I need alignment on the equal symbol and to save space sometimes I need 2 equations on the same line.

```
\begin{fleqn}[0pt]
\setlength{\jot}{6pt}
\begin{align*}
    &\int f(x) \ldots \mbox{long expression here} \ldots dx = F(x) + C \\
    &\int f(x) \ldots \mbox{long expression here} \ldots dx = F(x) + C \\
    &\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C &&\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C \\
    &\int f(x) \ldots \mbox{long expression here} \ldots dx = F_1(x) + C =  \\
    &\qquad\qquad = F_1(x) + C \\
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}
```

First I'm not satisfied, I can't set the point of alignment with 2 equations in one line and I can't align the equations on the equal sign. Most environment (`tabular`, `tabbed`, `split`,...) do only one job and when I try to mix them I always get some errors.

Second I would like to create a new environment with

```
\newenvironment{mathtable}
{ \begin{fleqn}[0pt] \setlength{\jot}{6pt} \begin{align*} }
{ \end{align*} \end{fleqn} }
```

But it show me an error, it seems I can't use `align` inside `newenvironment`. Did a lot of research, used the [environ package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/making-a-new-environment-combining-equation-and-split), used [`\csname`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13992/starred-equivalent-in-newenvironment) and so on, but I don't know how to build this environment.

Comment: The amsmath documentation documents that in an environment definition you need to use the `\align` `\endalign` forms not `\begin{align}` `\end{align}`

Comment: But then I have a generic error on `\begin{fleqn}`...

Comment: it's possible that the `aligned` environment of `amsmath` might be helpful, since it's meant to be embedded within another environment.

Comment: There is *no* `fleqn` environment.

Comment: @egreg: There is a `fleqn` environment with \usepackage{nccmath}.

Comment: @Mafra: Just an FYI: I used to include the `nccmath` package, but have abandoned it do to issues I encountered with `nccmath` and `minipages`. See [Is there a replacement for nccmath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-there-a-replacement-for-nccmath).

Answer (score 5):

You give too little information for giving advice about the first point.

For what concerns the second point, here's how you can define your `mathtable` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\newenvironment{mathtable}
  {\fleqn[0pt] \setlength{\jot}{6pt} \csname align*\endcsname}
  {\csname endalign*\endcsname\endfleqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{mathtable}
    &\int f(x) \ldots \mbox{long expression here} \ldots dx = F(x) + C \\
    &\int f(x) \ldots \mbox{long expression here} \ldots dx = F(x) + C \\
    &\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C &&\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C \\
    &\int f(x) \ldots \mbox{long expression here} \ldots dx = F_1(x) + C =  \\
    &\qquad\qquad = F_1(x) + C
\end{mathtable}

\end{document}
```

One can't use `\begin{foo}` and `\end{foo}` in the definition of a new environment, when `foo` is the name of an `amsmath` alignment environment. So one has to use the forms `\foo` and `\endfoo` in their places (or `\csname foo*\endcsname` and `\csname endfoo*\endcsname` for the *-variants).