# How do I align multiple separate `align` environment blocks?

Tags: spacing, amsmath

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}

\newcommand*{\scaleandcenter}[2]{{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}}}}
\newcommand*{\scalebig}[1]{\scaleandcenter{1.5}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\imp}{\mathop{\Rightarrow}}
\newcommand*{\Imp}{\mathbin{\scalebig{\imp}}}
\newcommand*{\blankrel}[1]{\mathrel{\phantom{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\Blank}{\blankrel{\Imp}}
\newcommand*{\Eq}{\mathrel{\scalebig{=}}}
\newcommand*{\apf}{\mathrel{\triangleleft}}
\newcommand*{\sgn}{\texttt{sgn}}

\begin{document}
    We can expect $n!$ injective functions from $[n]$ to $[n]$. Therefore, we will have 6 terms in the summation above, corresponding to each of the 6 permutations in $S_n$:
    \begin{align*}
        &\Blank \pi_1 = e, \sgn(\pi_2) = 1\\
        &\Imp \sgn(\pi_1) \prod_{j=1}^3 v_{\pi_1 \apf j, j} \\
        &\Eq \prod_{j=1}^3 v_{\pi_1 \apf j, j} \\
        &\Eq v_{1,1}v_{2,2}v_{3,3}
    \end{align*}

    \begin{align*}
        &\Blank \pi_2 = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 2\end{matrix}\right), \sgn(\pi_2) = -1\\
        &\Imp \sgn(\pi_2) \prod_{j=1}^3 v_{\pi_2 \apf j, j} \\
        &\Eq -\prod_{j=1}^3 v_{\pi_2 \apf j, j} \\
        &\Eq -v_{2,1}v_{1,2}v_{3,3}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

However, notice that the first block doesn't line up with the second (`\pi_1` doesn't line up with `\pi_2`); why is this? If you add more align blocks after the second one, they'll line up, it's just the first that is slightly "indented"?

Comment: is there some obstacle to have both in one `align` environment?  otherwise, you can't align equations. but from your example i can conclude, that you actually like to have all equation (in document) left aligned. is this a case?

Comment: @Zarko Yes I cannot put them all in one align block, because I have 6 such blocks, and they get cut off at the bottom of the page, rather than page breaking appropriately?

Comment: Add `\allowdisplaybreaks` to the preamble, and `align`s can be broken across pages.

Comment: and use `\intertext{...}` if you like to insert some text between your equation blocks.

Comment: I don't really see why you would expect the horizontal position on the page to be the same in both blocks though, in general it doesn't make sense to do it like that. On the other hand, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107033 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122069 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343911