# Custom environment shorthand for multiple environments

Tags: macros, environments

I am interested in doing something like the following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{customeq}{\begin{equation}\begin{split}}{\end{split}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}

This is an equation.
\begin{customeq}
x=5
\end{customeq}

\end{document}
```

However, when I try to do this, I get an error saying that `\begin{split}` has been ended by `\end{customeq}`.  Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: this looks quite a lot like [Making  a new environment combining equation and split](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3169)