# Asymptote environment wrapped in another environment doesn't work

Tags: errors, environments, asymptote

I am trying to create an environment that essentially centers and creates an asymptote diagram, given the diagram's code. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{asymptote}
\newenvironment{diagram}{\begin{center}\begin{asy}}{\end{asy}\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{diagram}
    draw((0, 0) -- (1, 1));
\end{diagram}

\end{document}
```

The code above gives the `Runaway argument? File ended while scanning use of \next` error. This also seems to be an Asymptote-specific error; if I replace the `\begin{asy}` and `\end{asy}` with something else, it works fine. This is similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/making-a-new-environment-combining-equation-and-split) question, but following the answer there doesn't work. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `asy` environment is type of verbatim environment, and as such it requires that the the literal string `\end{asy}` appears at the end of the environment.  Since you hide it inside `diagram` it doesn't find the `\end` and scans too far ahead in the file, eventually reaching its end and then you get an error that the file has ended:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test.tex
            
?
```

Fortunately it is rather easy to change the string that `asy` looks for to end the environment to be that of your own environment.  Here is a patch that defines `\asyenv{<name>}`, such that `\begin{asy}` will look for `\end{<name>}` to end the verbatim environment.  In your case you have to say `\asyenv{diagram}`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{asymptote}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\asy
  {\ProcessAsymptote{asy}}
  {\expandafter\ProcessAsymptote\expandafter{\asy@outer@env}}
  {}{\errmessage{Failed to patch asy}}
\def\asyenv#1{\def\asy@outer@env{#1}}%

\newenvironment{diagram}{%
  \begin{center}%
  \asyenv{diagram}%
  \begin{asy}%
}{%
  \end{asy}\end{center}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{diagram}
    draw((0, 0) -- (1, 1));
\end{diagram}

\end{document}
```

Comment: works beautifully, thanks!